# DjangoRestFramework ignoring custom error messages

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

This is my UserExtendedSerializer:

```
class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserExtendedSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the super() 
            for field in self.fields: # iterate over the serializer fields
                self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field # set the custom error message
                self.fields[field].error_messages['invalid'] = 'Select a valid %s.'%field # set the custom error message
    class Meta:
        model = UserExtended
        fields = ('country',)
```

This is my models.py:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    countryName = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    countryCode = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

My issue is, when the user submits an invalid type (Django expects an integer / pk value, but assume the user submits the string "a"), Django sends an error to the front end saying "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list." even though I overrode the "invalid" error messages in my serializer. How come the error message being sent to the front end is not "Select a valid country" but "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list." instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django validations are executed first, so you can set `country field` as read only and prevent django model validations, then in your `update/create` method, validate country and raises your error if is needed. Also you need to create your CountrySerializer

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #country serializer fields goes here

class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        country = CountrySerializer(read_only=True)
        class Meta:
            model = UserExtended
            fields = ('country',)

        def check_country(self):
            request = self.context['request']
            data = request.data
            country_data = data.get('country'):
            #Validated your country data
            #valid_country = .....
            if not valid_country:
                 raise serializers.ValidationError("Select a valid country")


        def create(self,validated_data):

            self.check_country()
            super(UserExtended,self).create(self,validated_data)

        def update(self,instance,validated_data):

            self.check_country()
            super(UserExtended,self).update(self,instance,validated_data)
```

Comment: Interesting. How can I view Django validators? Because I opened up the python shell and did "repr(UserExtendedSerializer())" and all I saw was "UserExtendedSerializer():\n country = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset.Country.objects.all())". If there were Django validators present on the Country field, wouldn't it show up when I do repr(UserExtendedSerializer())?

Comment: also, you used "check_country(self)". Should it be "validate_country(self)" instead? (because over here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation in the "Field-level Validation" section, it says "You can specify custom field-level validation by adding .validate_<field_name> methods to your Serializer subclass. These are similar to the .clean_<field_name> methods on Django forms."

Comment: @user2719875 I forgot to set country as readonly, so, when you put a field as read only, validate_<field_name> is not triggered. I edited my answer, check it out.

Comment: Thanks levi. In addition to your answer, I'd just like to point out that I was mistaken. The error message which was being raised wasn't even a Django Validation error in the first place, it was in fact actually just a field-level validation error which did not fall under the category of "invalid" (it fell under the "incorrect_type" category) so my "invalid" error message was not overriding the "incorrect_type" error message, rightly so. See here for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32928893/django-drf-how-can-i-view-a-list-of-all-validators-for-a-model-model-seria