# Django / DRF - How can I view a list of all validators for a model / model serializer field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-validation, django-serializer

This is my UserExtendedSerializer:

```
class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(UserExtendedSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # call the super() 
            for field in self.fields: # iterate over the serializer fields
                self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = 'Enter a valid %s.'%field # set the custom error message
                self.fields[field].error_messages['invalid'] = 'Select a valid %s.'%field # set the custom error message
    class Meta:
        model = UserExtended
        fields = ('country',)
```

and this is the UserExtended model:

```
class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
```

Now, when I try to create a user without entering a valid country, Django gives an error to the front end saying "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list". Where is this error message coming from? Because in my init function, I overrode the "invalid" error message to say "Select a valid country.", but that is not the message I receive.

Also, I opened up the shell and did

```
repr(UserExtendedSerializer())
```

and the output was:

```
UserExtendedSerializer():\n country = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset.Country.objects.all())
```

So no Django validators were listed here either. How do I view all the validators for a specific model / model serializer field?

Comment: Check the error in your server. Your user is getting a list on one of its fields instead of the foreign object's pk.

Comment: @cdvv7788 It's a 400 error, which is fine. It is receiving a list because of the end users input. My issue is not the error message itself but how do I see the list of validators on the Django serializer / model field? Because "self.fields[field].error_messages['invalid'] = 'Select a valid %s.'%field" is not overriding the error message so there must be another validator somewhere which I am not seeing (I eventually want to override the error message which the validator raises but I need to first find out where the error message is coming from in order to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Getting Validators for a particular serializer field:**

To get the validators for a particular serializer field, you can do:

```
my_field_validators = UserExtendedSerializer().fields['my_field'].validators
```

**Getting Validators for all the serializer fields:**

To get the validators for all the serializer fields in a dictionary, we can use dictionary comprehension.

```
{x:y.validators for x,y in UserExtendedSerializer().fields.items()}
```

**Getting serializer-level validators:**

To get the validators defined at the serializer level i.e. in the `Meta` class of the serializer, you can do:

```
UserExtendedSerializer().validators
```

**But this is not where the error comes from.**

None of the validators are generating this error message. The error is occurring because of passing invalid data to `UserExtendedSerializer` for the `country` field.

**DRF source code for `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`**

```
class PrimaryKeyRelatedField(RelatedField):
    default_error_messages = {
        'required': _('This field is required.'),
        'does_not_exist': _("Invalid pk '{pk_value}' - object does not exist."),
        'incorrect_type': _('Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received {data_type}.'), # error message
    }    

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get(pk=data)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            self.fail('does_not_exist', pk_value=data)
        except (TypeError, ValueError): # here error message is being generated
            self.fail('incorrect_type', data_type=type(data).__name__)
```

So this error message is coming from the default `incorrect_type` error message. You can use this key to change the error message if you want.

Comment: When I did "my_field_validators = UserExtendedSerializer().fields['country'].validators" the output was "[]". I then did "{x:y.validators for x,y in UserExtendedSerializer().fields.items()}" and the output was "{'country':[]}" and then when I did "UserExtendedSerializer().validators" the output was "[]". Where is the error message "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received list" coming from then? What validator is verifying that a pk value is expected, and throws the error message above when a pk value is not given? (when I ran the commands you provided, no validator shows up).

Comment: The error message is not coming from the `validators`. Empty `validators` list just means no `validators` are being used. The default error message `incorrect_type` contains this error message. Updated the ans to reflect the same.